# How can I get a Chinese text-to-speech software that can overcome the lack of pronunciations in certain tones?

Tags: pronunciation, software

I'm using some text-to-speech softwares to read some stuff (Narakeet, Mic Monster and Speechelo), but I also want to have them read each 声母 and 韵母 in the 1st tone. The problem is there are some Chinese syllables that don't have charaters in the 1st tone, like "ne" and "te".

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Chinese use Xunfei讯飞 good one, there are website or apps: https://www.xfyun.cn/services/online_tts

Recently, Microsoft made new version of Azure Speech, i think that one is best for most of languages.

You can try it with this tools:
https://github.com/LuckyHookin/edge-TTS-record
https://github.com/LokerL/tts-vue

Good Luck